# How to (using GUI) empty a flash drive's trash without emptying the computer's?

Tags: gui, external-hdd, trash

When you delete files from a flash drive or external hard drive, files go to a trash bin located physically in the drive.

But in the GUI, both the external drive's trash and the computer's trash are coalesced into one. When you empty the trash you are emptying both trashes. That also seems to be the case for OS X and Windows.

I could, obviously, delete the trash on the flash drive using the terminal, but it seems to me there should be a way of emptying the flash drive trash without emptying the computer's trash using the GUI.

Is there one in Ubuntu ?

Comment: as you said: "delete the trash on the flash drive using the terminal". Another alternative might be to open nautilus with gksu and navigate to the drive in question (showing hidden files) and dump it from there. It seems easier to use the terminal or simply not put things in the trash you don't wish to delete.

Comment: @ElderGeek Not all users are technical users. Not all users know or should know about terminal sessions or showing hidden files. There are a few children, housewives and grandmas using Ubuntu. For them is I'm asking the question for.

Comment: I pointed to both options in my comment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you open the flash drive press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or through menu *View > Show hidden files*, hidden folder should appear `.Trash-1000` or similar. Delete this folder like a normal file, you will be prompted with "Remove it permanently?", press the <kbd>Del</kbd> button. Or delete this folder by selecting it and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

Comment: Not all users are technical users. Not all users know or should know about terminal sessions or showing hidden files. There are a few children, housewives and grandmas using Ubuntu. For them is I'm asking the question for.

Comment: @user1598390 what Paul suggests is purely GUI, no terminal is mentioned.

Comment: @JacobVlijm ... or showing hidden files with arcane names.

Comment: You can go thru menu instead of CTRL+H, in your files: View > Show hidden files

Comment: Children are able to pick things up pretty quickly, and housewives and grandmas are smarter than you give them credit for. I think this is about as simple as this task can be made, without changing file manager things drastically.